# Rosjava + Android phone + Kinect, is it possible?

Tags: kinect, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

The announcement of the Java wrapper to run ROS on Android phones is really exciting. I was wondering how someone might connect a Kinect to an android phone to use it as a sensor? I'd like to build a small robot and an Android phone seems like a great alternative to a fully blown laptop.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10025/rosjava-+-android-phone-+-kinect,-is-it-possible?/) by [drcross](https://answers.ros.org/users/576/drcross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-05-22

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two thoughts:

1. You'll have the usual powering-the-Kinect problem. Just a USB port isn't enough; see the [Create <-> Kinect Tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20Kinect%20to%20an%20iRobot%20Create) for details on how to build a power supply in a particular case.
2. The Kinect (both the OpenNI and libfreenect versions) are in C[++], not Java. I don't know if user processes on Android have to be in Java, but just having ROSJava doesn't get you Kinect support out of the box.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-05-25**:
A related datapoint: a while back, I tried using a Kinect on embedded computer with a single-core 1.2GHz ARM processor.  That machine had a hard time keeping up with the data from the Kinect.  I summarized my experience (including source for a stripped down Kinect node) [here](https://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20110314.202103.b1c1acba.en.html).

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-05-23**:
I also do not believe that anyone has successfully demonstrated the USB Host interface is capable of handling the data rate produced by the Kinect.